# how to bind combobox values from sql server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net

below code binding data from  table but i need 1st item must be "select" i am using web forms how i can do it

```
{
    comboBox_city.DataSource = obj_dt;
    comboBox_city.ValueMember = "City_Name";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

`comboBox_city.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("---Select---",""));`

Comment: type or namespace can not be found

Comment: at which line of the code? Are you binding the comboBox? like `comboBox_city.DataBind()`?

Comment: obj_dt = obj_file.all_tables_cstvpb();//from business layer.i am using 3tier                                                                     
            comboBox_state.DataSource = obj_dt;
            comboBox_state.ValueMember = "State_Name";

Comment: are you getting error at `obj_dt = obj_file.all_tables_cstvpb();`?

Comment: obj_dt = obj_file.all_tables_cstvpb();
            //comboBox_state.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", ""));//at this line
            comboBox_state.DataSource = obj_dt;
            comboBox_state.ValueMember = "State_Name";

Comment: May be that column doesn't exist in the object list. Check out what values you are getting from data access class.

Answer (score 0):

If its ASP.Net, then you should use

```
private void BindCombo()
{
  var dt = SomeMethodReturningData();
  comboBox_city.DataSource = dt;
  comboBox_city.DataValueField ="State_Code"; //assume
  comboBox_city.DataTextField= "State_Name"
  comboBox_city.DataBind();
  comboBox_city.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("---Select---","-1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox_city.Items.Insert(0,"---Select---");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the item manually, using the smart tag or items property. And then set the AppendDataBoundItems property to true.